# Android: onClick() didn't called while running contacts application on Android phone

Tags: android

I am trying to get all my Phone / Sim contacts in list and while selecting particular contact I am getting email address for that contact. When I run this application in android simulator I am getting perfect output but while I use this application in Android phone it will shows all contact in list but `onClick()` for selection it will crash the application.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: you should post some code in support of your question ...

Comment: If you have got solution please let me know.

Comment: I agree with Vineet..Always send some code snippet with question.